# Creating relation between two tables with prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

i'm working in a NextJs project that uses prisma, but i never used it before. I created a relation between two fields, than i ran `yarn prisma generate` and retrieved it with `prisma.foo.findMany({})`. Everything worked fine at the local server, but i could not deploy it to vercel, i got an error saying that the field does not exist on that table.

I have the users table

```
model users {
  id                    Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  username              String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  email                 String    @db.VarChar(255)
  vehicle               Int?
  vehicleRef type_vehicles? @relation(fields: [vehicle], references: [id])
}
```

And i have the vehicle table

```
model type_vehicles {
  id         Int  @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  name       String    @db.VarChar(255)

  users      users[ ]
}
```

The `vehicle` is the `id` of some vehicle of `type_vehicles`, so the field `'vehicle'` references to the field `'id'` of type_vehicles. Correct?

After that i ran `yarn prisma generate` and retrieved it as

```
const usersTmp = await prisma.users.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      vehicleRef:{
            select:{
              name: true,
            },
          },
      updated_at: true,
 },
});
```

Am i doing something wrong? I'm only getting the error when deploying, saying that `vehicleRef` does not exist on `users`

Comment: Do you run `prisma generate` in your deployment?

Comment: "i got an error saying that the field does not exist on that table" -> can you share the exact error message please :)

Comment: @some-user no, how could i run it when deploying?

Comment: How do you build and deploy?

Comment: Vercel deploys it automatically whenever i commit to the branch. Another interesting thing is that when i run `yarn build` it works ok, doesn't throw any error

Comment: Do you have `prisma generate` in your vercel build script? https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-vercel

Comment: Yes, we do. But the way i created the relation is correct? Would you do it differently?

Comment: @nburk Unfortunatelly i don't have access to the build logs, so i can't recall exactly the error message :/.

Comment: @nburk i remember that it was saying that i don't have vehicleRef in usersSelect. Might be the way i'm retrieving it at prisma.users.findMany ?

Comment: Related GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/15739